# How to install poppler >= 0.73 on ubuntu 20.04 (any change since 18.04?)

Tags: server, 20.04, poppler

I have seen the first answer to [How to install poppler 0.73 on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112856/how-to-install-poppler-0-73-on-ubuntu-18-04) which basically consists of the following steps:

Compile and install Poppler 0.73 with checkinstall to the /usr/local:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev cmake checkinstall
sudo apt-get build-dep libpoppler-cpp-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.73.0.tar.xz
tar -xf poppler-0.73.0.tar.xz
cd poppler-0.73.0

mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
sudo checkinstall make install
```

Define the environment variable R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH to inform R about the Poppler libraries in /usr/local/lib:

```
echo "export R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" >> .bashrc
```

Compile the pdftools R-package inside R-shell:

```
install.packages("pdftools")
```

Test it from R-shell with any pdf-file

```
> pdftools::pdf_data(pdf="/usr/share/cups/data/default.pdf")
[1]]
[1] width  height x      y      space  text  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I wanted to know:

- would the answer also apply to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?  - I tried it, and it worked.  However I realised later this is not be the best solution (see answers below).
- would it also apply to any more recent version of poppler?  - didn't try, as I didn't want to mess up my working setup with version 0.73.

Here is the output of `dpkg -l | grep -i poppler` after performing the above install (this is useful to determine how to uninstall, see below):

```
# dpkg -l | grep -i poppler
ii  build                                20200518-1                         amd64        poppler-0.73.0
ii  poppler-data                         0.4.9-2                            all          encoding data for the poppler PDF rendering library
#
```

Comment: What is the question really? The 20.04 LTS already has [fresh Poppler 0.86](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libpoppler-dev).

Comment: sorry I never found that Poppler 0.86 on 20.04 LTS server.  But then I'm not sure what I should have done to find and install it ?

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i poppler` to the question body.

Comment: output has been added

Comment: See also: [How to install the latest version of poppler?](https://askubuntu.com/q/781552/327339). That Q&A seems to be the most-visited and active.

Comment: Also, I just put great detail in an answer on upgrading poppler for Ubuntu 20.04 specifically, here: [How to install/upgrade to the latest version of Poppler/`pdftoppm` on Linux Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74313286/4561887)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At first you need to remove self-compiled deb-package of Poppler named *build*:

```
sudo apt-get purge build
```

To install actual version of Poppler use package [from repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libpoppler-dev):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpoppler-dev
```

And at next time - start from repository, build packages **only** if they are not available in the repositories. More detailed explanation [is here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147627/66509).

Comment: Thanks a lot Norbert, that answers how to install it.  I suppose I would have first to undo the installation of Poppler 0.73? (how?)
And more fundamentally, if I may ask, how could I have checked and found out by myself that the package existed with that name in a repository (I'm not even sure which repository, nor whether it has to be added to my /etc/apt/sources.list file) and for that version of Ubuntu? (other than asking on Ask Ubuntu)?

Comment: See updated answer above. About packages the APT command-line utils and  http://packages.ubuntu.com site provide information about the official repositories. More info: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/addremove.html.en for desktop and https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management for server.

Comment: many  thanks for the additional links, much appreciated!

Comment: In my case I needed `pdfinfo` which I had to install using `apt install poppler-utils`.

Answer (score 13):

Use the following method to install Poppler in Ubuntu 20.04

#### Download Poppler

```
wget https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz
tar -xvf poppler-21.09.0.tar.xz
```

#### Install some dependencies(if missing)

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3 libnss3-dev
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

#### Make install

```
cd poppler-21.09.0/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release   \
       -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr  \
       -DTESTDATADIR=$PWD/testfiles \
       -DENABLE_UNSTABLE_API_ABI_HEADERS=ON \
       ..
make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: I also needed to do `sudo apt install libopenjp2-7-dev -y` (poppler-22.04.0)

Comment: @CodeProcessor Thank you for saving me a lot of headache figuring out the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you!   Installing libpoppler-dev and poppler-utils did not resolve the issue for me - only building from source as you've describe here, worked.   (Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.8, using with pdf2image which is what was complaining that it couldn't find poppler)